# populating struct fields in a separate function in C

Tags: c, struct

getting empty values in the struct for this implementation since pointers are freed after call to myFunc ends. what's a good way of populating a struct when its fields are populated in a different function?

```
struct Poke {
    char *name;
    char *type;
};

void myFunc(struct Poke *p) {

    char fish[5] = "fish";
    char *name = fish;
    char fillet[8] = "fillet";
    char *type = fillet;

    p->name = name;
    p->type = type;

}

int main () {

    struct Poke p;
    myFunc(&p);

    printf("%s\n", (&p)->name);
    printf("%s\n", (&p)->type);

}
```

Comment: You are assigning pointers to local variables. The local variables exist only while the function `myFunc()` is executing; when the function returns to `main()`, its local variables go out of existence. As @PSkocik says, you may consider allocating memory for `p.name` and `p.type`, for example with `malloc()` or `strdup()`.

Comment: `p->name = strdup(name);` and free name when you are done with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you realize that the memory allocated for `fish` and `fillet` is deallocated when the function returns.

So you need memory that persists after the function call.

So you go and do some research and discover C's memory allocation functions like `malloc` and `free`. You will also need C's string handling functions like `strcpy`.

Go read about all the functions you can find in the include headers ["stdlib.h"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) and ["string.h"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Comment: let's say I call my_func multiple times so I can get different values for the struct fields, does this mean everytime I call the function, i'd have to call free first so I can reallocate that same space in memory?

Comment: @user3226932 Yes, you'd have to call `free()` on `p->name` and `p->type`, then call `malloc()` to allocate enough memory for the new strings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this particular case is that `char fish[5] = "fish";` creates a local variable and copies the string `"fish"` into it. So assigning `char *name = fish;` then `p->name = name;` stores the address of this local variable in your struct (and the same goes for `p->type`).

You can avoid this by directly storing the addresses of the string literals:

```
char *name = "fish";
char *type = "fillet";
```

---

And on a somewhat unrelated note, you don't need to dereference the address of `p` here:

```
printf("%s\n", (&p)->name);
printf("%s\n", (&p)->type);
```

The following is sufficient:

```
printf("%s\n", p.name);
printf("%s\n", p.type);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is by allocating memory for the strings inside the structure itself, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Poke
{
    char name[64];
    char type[64];
};

void myFunc(struct Poke *p)
{
    char fish[5] = "fish";
    char fillet[8] = "fillet";

    strncpy(p->name, fish, 64);
    strncpy(p->type, fillet, 64);
}

int main ()
{
    struct Poke p;
    myFunc(&p);

    printf("%s\n", p.name);
    printf("%s\n", p.type);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to make the strings static (static const for completeness) so they are persistent:

```
void myFunc(struct Poke *p)
{
    static const char fish[5] = "fish";
    char *name = fish;
    static const char fillet[8] = "fillet";
    char *type = fillet;
    p->name = name;
    p->type = type;
}
```

Or you need to define your structure members as char arrays and copy the string in:

```
struct Poke
{
    char name[5];
    char type[8];
};

void myFunc(struct Poke *p)
{
    strcpy(p->name, "fish");
    strcpy(p->type, "fillet");
}
```